# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location.city is not a column defined in this metadata

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cql3, datastax-java-driver

Here is my CQL tables

```
CREATE TYPE ks_demo.location (
lat float,
lon float,
locName text,
city text,
state text,
country text,
pin int
);    

create table publishMsg
(
    rowKey uuid,
    msgId timeuuid,
    postedBy text,
    postedById uuid,
    title text,
    details text,
    tags set<text>,
    location frozen<location>,
    blocked boolean,
    anonymous boolean,
    hasPhotos boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY(rowKey, msgId)      
)

create table publishMsg_by_user
(
    userId uuid,
    msgId timeuuid,
    postedBy text,
    title text,
    details text,
    tags set<text>,
    location frozen<location>,
    blocked boolean,
    anonymous boolean,
    hasPhotos boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY(rowKey, msgId)      
)
```

Here is datastax java query

```
Select.Where query = QueryBuilder.select().column("userId").column("msgId")
.column("location.city")
       .from(AppConstants.KEYSPACE, "publishMsg_by_user")
       .where(QueryBuilder.eq("userId",userId));
```

If I do

```
ResultSet  execute         = session.execute(query);
Iterator<Row> iterator        = execute.iterator();        
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    Row row = iterator.next();
    row.getString("location.city")
}
row.getString("location.city")
```

it is showing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location.city is not a column defined in this metadata
```

Comment: What version of the driver are you using?

Comment: @manish your query mentions 'userId' column but it's not in the table definition. Should it be?

Comment: Could you post the CQL for `publishMsg_by_user` instead of just `publishMsg`? We don't have all the information here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
String city = row.getUDTValue("location").getString("city")
```